# Maven Wrapper install plugins locally

Tags: maven

I'm using Maven Wrapper for the first time and I am trying to run a command './mvnw -B openl:test' locally but I keep getting the error that no plugin found for prefix 'openl' in the current project and in the plugins groups. I looked in the .m2 directory and I do see the openl maven plugin there so I not sure why it's not working.  I installed the plugin running './mvnw clean install' after added the dependency to the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openl.rules</groupId>
    <artifactId>openl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.21.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use plugins with maven you need to declare it under "plugin" section in pom.xml. In your case it would look like this:

```
<build>
  [...]
  <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.openl.rules</groupId>
          <artifactId>openl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>5.21.9</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

  </plugins>
  [...]
</build>
```